# Very slow unordered_map clearing

Tags: c++, windows

I have this code that optimizes my mesh loaded from obj file:

```
PROFILE("Started optimizations.");
vector<float>* vs = new vector<float>();
unordered_map<string, int>* hm = new unordered_map<string, int>();
unordered_map<string, int>::const_iterator it;
UINT32 floatsInVertex = vertexSize / sizeof(float);
float* vertex = new float[floatsInVertex];
for (SIZE i = 0; i < nFaces; i++) {
    Face& face = faces[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < Face::FACE_SIZE; j++) {
        UINT32 index = face.indices_[j];
        UINT32 vInd = 0;
        UINT32 offset = index * vertexSize + posOffset;
        memcpy(&vertex[vInd++], &vertices[offset + 0], sizeof(float));
        memcpy(&vertex[vInd++], &vertices[offset + sizeof(float)], sizeof(float));
        memcpy(&vertex[vInd++], &vertices[offset + 2 * sizeof(float)], sizeof(float));
        if (face.hasNormals_) {
            index = face.normIndices_[j];
            offset = index * vertexSize + normOffset;
            memcpy(&vertex[vInd++], &vertices[offset + 0], sizeof(float));
            memcpy(&vertex[vInd++], &vertices[offset + sizeof(float)], sizeof(float));
            memcpy(&vertex[vInd++], &vertices[offset + 2 * sizeof(float)], sizeof(float));
        }
        if (face.hasUV_) {
            index = face.texIndices_[j];
            offset = index * vertexSize + uvOffset;
            memcpy(&vertex[vInd++], &vertices[offset + 0], sizeof(float));
            memcpy(&vertex[vInd++], &vertices[offset + sizeof(float)], sizeof(float));
        }
        string v(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(vertex), vertexSize);
        it = hm->find(v);
        if (hm->end() == it) {
            if (useShort) {
                indexArray->push_back(vs->size() / floatsInVertex);
            }
            else {
                indexArrayInt->push_back((UINT32) vs->size() / floatsInVertex);
            }
            hm->insert(pair<string, int>(v, vs->size() / floatsInVertex));
            for (SIZE i = 0; i < floatsInVertex; i++) {
                vs->push_back(vertex[i]);
            }
        }
        else {
            if (useShort) {
                indexArray->push_back(it->second);
            }
            else {
                indexArrayInt->push_back(it->second);
            }
        }
    }
}
PROFILE("Deleting hash map with size: %d.", hm->size());
LOGI("A");
delete hm;
LOGI("B");
PROFILE("Hash map deleted.");
```

Result for ~8.5MB model is this:

```
DEBUG: Started optimizations. Time: 0 (ms).
DEBUG: Deleting hash map with size: 194886. Time: 6879 (ms).
INFO: A
INFO: B
DEBUG: Hash map deleted. Time: 13046 (ms).
```

My PROFILE function just prints the time since last PROFILE call.
As you can see, unordered map of size 194886 takes ~7s to be deleted. Time is approximately same for debug and release versions. Is this normal? How can I cut off this time?

**[EDIT]** Same code on linux:

```
DEBUG: Started optimizations. Time: 0 (ms).
DEBUG: Deleting hash map with size: 194886. Time: 141(ms).
INFO: A
INFO: B
DEBUG: Hash map deleted. Time: 35(ms).
```

Its waaaaaaaaaaaay faster than windows version.

**[EDIT2]** My question is: How to speed this code up in windows to match linux?

Comment: Even if somebody would say this is normal, you know it is not.

Comment: Argh: naked `new` and `delete`, `reinterpret_cast` and `memcpy`. But those annoyances aside, where exactly in the above code are you clearing the `unordered_map`?

Comment: delete hm; (Look at the end of code.) Why new, delete, reinterpret_cast and memcpy are annoyances?

Comment: `unordered_map<string, int>* hm = new unordered_map<string, int>();` Why not simply: `unordered_map<string, int> hm;`?

Comment: It was like this at first, but then the lag would occur just after function returns, so I put it on heap for easier profiling.

Comment: Deleting the map means deallocating 194886 pairs that contain a `std::string` each, which implies calling `operator delete`, in the map's order of iteration, which is likely not the same order the buffers were allocated. That means a **lot** of work for the memory manager to defragment adjacent blocks into a contiguous memory region. Is it surprising that this is slow?

Comment: Did you ever make any progress on this? I noticed similar things with unordered_map lackluster performance in my code (MSVC 2010).

Comment: It was enough performance for me, so I left it as is.